# Como eu poderia enviar mensagens da cloud para o Android ?

Tags: android

Sei da existência do [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) , mas parece-me demasiado complexo , existe uma maneira mais fácil?

Caso não saibam nenhuma e se me quiserem explicar melhor o [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) fico agradecido.

Comment: Por favor corrija o titulo da sua pegunta e a descrição. aparentemente o titulo não tem nada haver com a descrição. Seria melhor algo como "Como eu poderia enviar mensagens da cloud para o Android ? "

Comment: Tem razão já esta corrigido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O parse.com tem um serviço de push bem simples de utilizar.

1. Seta as permissões web
2. Inicializa o serviço na sua aplicação no método OnCreate

   `Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");`
3. Habilita para receber notificação

   ```
   ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
     @Override
     public void done(ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
         Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
       } else {
         Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Depois é so enviar o push pela interface web:
[image]

Segue documentação https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: Ismael, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Poderia trazer um pouco do conteúdo do link para o corpo da sua resposta? Links constantemente quebram, sendo assim, resposta que se baseiam apenas no link acabam ficando obsoletas mais rapidamente e são removidas. Entretanto, sempre é bom deixar o link como referência :)

Comment: Tentei melhorar a resposta :D